# Insert key and value into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code

```
$array = array('o' => 'one', 't' => 'three', 'f' => 'four');
array_push($array, array('s' => 'six'));
print_r($array);
```

that insert new key and value into the array , but when i print the new $array it returned this

```
Array ( [o] => one [t] => three [f] => four [0] => Array ( [s] => six ) )
```

i need to return like this

```
Array ( [o] => one [t] => three [f] => four [s] => six )
```

how to remove `[0] => Array ()` from the array ?

Comment: `$array['s'] = 'six'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_push` is intended for lists.

```
$arr = array(5, 6, 7);
array_push($arr, 8); // array(5, 6, 7, 8);
```

You can add elements to arrays in many ways, this is one:

```
$array = array('o' => 'one', 't' => 'three', 'f' => 'four');
$array["s"] = "six";
```

Here is another:

```
$array = array_merge($array, array("s" => "six"));
```

---

PHP treats *lists* like `array(1, 2, 3);` differently than associative arrays like `array("foo" => "bar");`. The differences are minor, but they show up with functions like `array_push`.